# Blazor scrollbar stays on the bottom after sorting or paging

Tags: blazor, scrollbar, mudblazor

*The issue: The scrollbar stays at the bottom after sorting or paging the table, but I would prefer if it would jump up.*

I have a MudTable with fixed header and scrollbar. My problem is that when I use sorting or paging, the scrollbar stays on the bottom, instead of jumping to the top.

Example image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebw9s.png)

I've noticed this is the default behavior in the examples on mudblazor.com.

Any ideas how can this be fixed?

My table looks something like this:

```
<MudTable @ref="@table" Loading="@loading" ServerData="new Func<TableState, Task<TableData<MYClass>>>(LoadData)" Hover="true" Striped="true" Bordered="false" Elevation="0" Outlined="true"
          FixedHeader="@fixed_header" Height="@(fixed_header ? "75vh" : string.Empty)" RowsPerPage="@currentPerPage" RowsPerPageChanged="@PerpageChange" SortLabel="Sort By" AllowUnsorted="false"
          OnRowClick="OnToggledChanged" T="MYClass">
   .
   .
   .
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel InitialDirection="SortDirection.Ascending" SortLabel="label1" T="MYClass">Something</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortLabel="label2" T="MYClass">Something</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortLabel="label3" T="MYClass">Something</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        <MudTh></MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        .
        .
        .
    </RowTemplate>
    <PagerContent>
        <MudTablePager PageSizeOptions="pageSizeOptions" />
    </PagerContent>
</MudTable>
<MudSwitch Checked="@fixed_header" CheckedChanged="@headerChangedCallback">Fixed Header</MudSwitch>
```

Comment: https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/5445 I think there is no C# function to scroll. You might need to resort to calling JS function from your component in C#. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75302392/scroll-mudtable-to-make-selected-item-visible